# how to scanf a global variable outside the main?

Tags: c

I have a problem ,how to make an array `vertextDegree [nbColours]`  with  `nbColours`  elements in it ,but the "nbColours" unknown and I have to get it get it from a file . 
look at the code 
so what can I do to solve this problem ?

```
int nbEdges,nbVetices, nbColours ;
typedef struct st_graphVertex 
{
    int index;
    int colour;
    int val ;
    int vertexDegree[nbColours]; // it won't work because nbColours unknown     
                                 //  here and I want get it from file in the main                    
    struct st_graphVertex *next;        
    t_edgeList *out;
}t_grapheVertex;
```

Comment: Execute scanf in the loop from which runs nbColours times.

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C99 there is a special syntax for this, although it is limited to only one array per `struct` (which is OK in your case) - put the array as the last member, and drop its size, like this:

```
typedef struct st_graphVertex 
{
    int index;
    int colour;
    int val ;
    struct st_graphVertex *next;        
    t_edgeList *out;
    int vertexDegree[];   
}t_grapheVertex;
```

Now the size of your array is flexible: you can decide what it should be at runtime. Moreover, different `st_graphVertex` values can have this size set differently (although in such cases it's typical to put `nbColours` with the specific size as a field in the same `struct`).

The "payment" for using this trick is inability to allocate such `struct`s on the stack or in the global or static memory. You must allocate them dynamically, like this:

```
t_grapheVertex *vertex = malloc(sizeof(t_grapheVertex)+sizeof(int)*nbColours);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in pre-C99 or in non-last members. Instead, you can make that member a fixed-size pointer:

```
int* vertexDegree;
```

And make it point to an array of appropriate size known at runtime:

```
myVertex.vertexDegree = malloc(nbColours*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using [Struct Hack](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=struct+hack), which is however similar to what [*dasblinkenlight*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18672162/2628863) told in his answer.